# PHP MySQL query with variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a mysql fetch using a variable in my sql query.. Unfortunately I have no idea why the query is not working.

After the $_GET I have the echo to make sure that that was actually working, which it is, but the error seems to be occurring where the actually query is going

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$scout_id = $_GET['scout_id'];
echo "scout_id: ".$scout_id;

/*This is where the error is */
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM scouts WHERE scout_id='$scout_id' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

var_dump($row);
?>
```

If anyone would be able to help I would be most appreciative!

Comment: Your query is subject to SQL injections and is a security hazard.  Never use user input (GET, POST, COOKIE) directly in a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `mysqli` with `mysql`

Change

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

To

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: Oh my goodness you are a genius! Thank you so much! 

I completely overlooked that part.